Does Light Behave the Same in Crystal-Field Splitting, PPL Pleochroism, and XPL Interference Color?
My understanding in electromagnetic radiation is pretty weak; I learned of crystal-field splitting, where d-orbitals cause photons in visible light, and now we are covering how light shows up in a petrographic microscope. Two types were covered:

Pleochroism: Rotate a mineral sample, and the light will change. This will show up for PPL. Light is absorbed.


Interference Color: Due to refraction, light slows down, causing a lag that I assume splits visible white light into its components, and exaggerates the color profile when viewed in the microscope.

However, I realize that I do not really know what is going on in each of these:

I think crystal field splitting is caused by electrons releasing photons in the visible light region.


I think PPL is also a release of photons, and because of how small microscope samples are, crystal field splitting can not show the most distinct of colors.


XPL is described as double refraction, but it only makes sense in my mind when I describe it with diffraction, as refraction bends light; refraction can not split light to my knowledge.

The point of all this is I am now forced to understand how extinction works, but I am unsure how to understand it because I can only understand light not showing up when destructive interference occurs, but destructive interference is never mentioned. At this point I think I am failing to understand basic concepts.
What actually causes the color to show up in the three processes? I.e., what basic physics property undergirds each representation of color? Why is scattering of light not discussed in any of this? Why is diffraction not discussed in any of this?
As a point of reference, this is introductory Mineralogy.

Perhaps modeling electron-photon (and phonon) interactions as vibrations in a lattice might help you visualize the phenomena: https://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/iss/kap_4/illustr/i4_1_1.html, and se these course notes: https://kik.creol.ucf.edu/documents/ose5312notes.pdf

I will read these when I get the time. In essence, I just want to know what assumptions are present with each model.
